# rbenv: is it safe to embed a "bundle exec" call in the shims?

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv

rbenv requires you to manually run "bundle exec" if you're running an executable from a gem, to avoid loading a different version of that gem compared with your Gemfile.

Are there any downsides to having the rbenv shims run "bundle exec" when a Gemfile is present in the current directory? It's a somewhat naive approach, because it doesn't handle Gemfile's that are further up the directory tree, but I don't need that behavior. The change would also make sure the current shim isn't named "bundle" or there could be an infinite recursion.

Patch:

```
diff --git a/libexec/rbenv-rehash b/libexec/rbenv-rehash
index eebc4d3..00f4ec0 100755
--- a/libexec/rbenv-rehash
+++ b/libexec/rbenv-rehash
@@ -38,7 +38,14 @@ create_prototype_shim() {
 #!/usr/bin/env bash
 set -e
 export RBENV_ROOT="$RBENV_ROOT"
-exec rbenv exec "\${0##*/}" "\$@"
+# This only handles Gemfile in current dir
+if [[ \$RBENV_AUTO_BUNDLE = '1' && -e Gemfile && \`basename \$0\` != 'bundle' ]]; then
+  exec 3>/dev/tty
+  echo "rbenv: Using Gemfile" >&3
+  exec rbenv exec bundle exec "\${0##*/}" "\$@"
+else
+  exec rbenv exec "\${0##*/}" "\$@"
+fi
 SH
   chmod +x "$PROTOTYPE_SHIM_PATH"
 }
```

You must set environment variable RBENV_AUTO_BUNDLE=1 to enable the auto "bundle exec" behavior.

If there's enough demand I might submit a patch.

To apply the patch, just put the patch file in your .rbenv dir, and run

```
git apply PATCHFILE
```

To test the patch, you'll have to delete your shims and run "rbenv rehash".

To undo:

```
git apply -R PATCHFILE
```

or

```
git checkout -- libexec/rbenv-rehash
```

then recreate the shims again.

It does seem that vim will run some ruby when you load a ruby file, and bundle exec will be used with that too. You could disable the auto behavior via `let $RBENV_AUTO_BUNDLE=0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> rbenv requires you to manually run "bundle exec" if you're running an
>   executable from a gem, to avoid loading a different version of that
>   gem compared with your Gemfile.

Unless you use the [rbenv-bundler](https://github.com/carsomyr/rbenv-bundler) plugin, which IMHO is a saner approach than trying to reimplemented that behavior yourself. If there's anything missing from that plugin, rather contribute it there.